# How to add my app in 'RECOMMENDED APPS FOR YOU' row on Home page in Fire TV devices

Tags: amazon-fire-tv

How can I add my app to the 'RECOMMENDED APPS FOR YOU' row on Fire TV devices?
[Fire TV screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/haW2W.jpg)

It is possible to show my app in 'RECOMMENDED APPS FOR YOU' in row on Home Screen in fire TV, without install app in device.